# if statements and textinput value

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement, textfield

If I have a textfield, and I want to use an IF statement to check that text field, for example, I can do this

```
if (thistxt.text=="query")
{  
thisbool = "true";
}
```

Now let's say I want to use an IF statement to call upon that same textfield but I don't want to pull that entire phrase, (query) maybe just the beginning or end of it, how could I do something like that? Let's say I want to activate the IF statement if that textfield contains or ends with "ery" but is not necessary perfectly equal to "ery".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TextField.text`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#text) returns a `String`. Strings have the [`indexOf()` method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#indexOf()) which returns the position of a substring if it is found, otherwise returning `-1`. Meaning you can do this:

```
if (thistxt.text.indexOf('ery') >= 0) {
    thisbool = true;
}
```

There is also the more advanced [`match()` method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#match()) that uses either strings or [regular expressions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html):

```
if (thistxt.text.match('ery').length > 0) {
    thisbool = true;
}
```

---

To match strings at the beginning or end of your input you have to use regex. Fortunately the pattern for these types of matches is trivial when compared to the full capabilities of regex - something like:

```
if (thistxt.text.match(/^ery/).length > 0) // Match at the start.
if (thistxt.text.match(/ery$/).length > 0) // Match at the end.
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107807/discussion-between-koden-and-marty).